Connect-AzAccount OAuth login window not showing in .Net GUI since changing laptop
I have a powershell script which runs in a very basic Systems.Windows.Forms .Net GUI wrapper, with the first step in this script being to prompt the user to login to Azure through a Microsoft login window, which is triggered via the Connect-AzAccount script.
This is the very start of this script that triggers the auth flow:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "[Azure Subscription ID]"

The full script was compiled into an executable and worked fine for a while, but once me and a few others changed our laptops (to the same OS version, just an updated spec), the pop-up no longer appeared when the executable was run, **only **when running from inside powershell itself (not practical for end-users).
Because the pop-up did not show, the authentication challenge fails and the rest of the script fails to complete (as it relies on an auth token generated by that initial challenge). The following errors are shown on screen (in the order I have laid them out):





Is there a straightforward fix for this that doesn't involve completely re-writing the authentication logic and setting up a custom MSAL handler as the error suggests? I'd really prefer to avoid this if possible.
I assumed it would be certain cmdlets/ packages not being installed so made sure to install the Az and Az.Accounts modules, set execution policy to "RemoteSigned", ensured .Net framework 4.8 was installed, set default browser and ensured pop-ups weren't blocked.
Again this allowed the script to be run from inside Powershell, the pop-up displays and it all works fine, its just within the GUI where this issue happens.
Tested using Windows Powershell 5.1.22621.2506 and Powershell 7.4.2

I don't have a solution for your problem, but I faced similar issue with my PowerShell scripts with Connect-AzAccount and connect-AzureAD after reinstalling the OS. All I can think of is that something changed in either AZ Module the PowerShell version, that is no longer compatible. My workaround was to make Edge defautl browser, run the script as local admin. add Azure account to local Work account. It would still error out, but the Popup for authentication would allow login, and the script would work. Most likely not a solution for your problem. I was told to rewrite AzureAD script in Graph.

Thanks for your comments, I was able to resolve this ultimately, as per my answer, might be worth looking at this for your issue and see if it helps?

Managed to resolve this by adding this into the script before Connect-AzAccount:
Update-AzConfig -EnableLoginByWam $false

It looks as though we inadvertently moved to a version of the Az Powershell module which uses "WAM" (Web Account Manager) by default for Azure login flows.
This was breaking the script because it meant that rather than reaching out to a Web Browser for login, it was trying to do it from within powershell itself, which the .Net GUI was unable to handle.
Adding this script disables WAM and forces Connect-AzAccount to use web browser instead, thus resolving the issue.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-interactive?view=azps-12.0.0
